# Continuous $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying $f\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}}\right) = \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all continuous $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that satisfy
> $$f\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}}\right) = \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}.$$

I tried to rewrite this equation in the form of Cauchy's Functional Equation and use continuous property to conclude. But , I didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $f(x) = Ax^2+B$ are solutions. Let us show that those are the only solutions.

Observe for any $\lambda>0$, we see that
\begin{align}
f\left(\lambda\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\right)=f\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda^2x^2+\lambda^2y^2}{2}} \right) = \frac{f(\lambda x) + f(\lambda y)}{2}.
\end{align}

Set $y=0$ and $\lambda = \sqrt{2}$, then we see that
\begin{align}
f(|x|) = \frac{f(\sqrt{2} x) + f(0)}{2} = \frac{f(-\sqrt{2}x)+f(0)}{2}
\end{align}
which means $f(x) = f(-x)$ for all $x$.

Consider $g(x) = f(x)-f(0)$. Clearly, we have that $g(0) = 0$. Moreover, we see that
\begin{align}
c = f\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\right)- f\left(0\right) = \frac{f(x)-f(0)+f(y)-f(0)}{2}= \frac{g(x)+g(y)}{2}.
\end{align}
At this point, $g(x)$ should be $Ax^2$. Note that we have
\begin{align}
g\left(\frac{\lambda |x|}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}g(\lambda x) = \frac{1}{2} g(-\lambda x).
\end{align}

Let us assume $g(1) \neq 0$. Define $h(x) = g(x)/g(1)$, then $h(1) = 1$ and
\begin{align}
h\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{g(1)}g\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{g(1)}\frac{g(x)+g(y)}{2}= \frac{h(x)+h(y)}{2}.
\end{align}

As of now, $h(x)$ should be $x^2$. Note that $h(x) = 2h(|x|/\sqrt{2})$

Consider
\begin{align}
F(x)=&\ \frac{1}{2}(h(x+1/2)-h(x-1/2)) = h\left( \frac{|x+1/2|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-h\left(\frac{|x-1/2|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
=&\ h\left( \sqrt{\frac{|x-1/2|^2+\sqrt{2|x|}^2}{2}}\right)-h\left(\frac{|x-1/2|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}h(\sqrt{2 |x|}) = h(\sqrt{|x|}).
\end{align}
It's clear that $F(0) = 0$. Finally, note that
\begin{align}
F(x+y)-F(x)-F(y) =&\ h(\sqrt{|x+y|})-h(\sqrt{|x|})-h(\sqrt{|y|)}\\
=&\ h(\sqrt{|x+y|}) -\frac{1}{2}[h(\sqrt{2|x|})+h(\sqrt{2|y|)}]\\
=&\ h(\sqrt{|x+y|})-h(\sqrt{\frac{2|x+y|}{2}} ) =0.
\end{align}

Note, for the last equality, I used the fact that $h(\sqrt{2}\sqrt{|x|})= h(\operatorname{sgn}(x)\sqrt{2|x|})$.

I will leave the case $g(1) = 0$ to the reader.

**Remark**: There might be a slicker way.

Comment: I think it could be easier to first define $G:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ with $G(x)=f\left(\sqrt x\right)$, and get $G\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)=\frac{G(x)+G(y)}2$. This is the well-known *Jensen's functional equation*, and its solutions are of the form $G(x)=A(x)+b$ for some constant $b\in\mathbb R$ and some [Additive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map) $A:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$. Continuous additive functions are linear; i.e. of the form $A(x)=ax$ for some constant $b\in\mathbb R$, and using evenness of $f$, we can conclude $f(x)=ax^2+b$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Where did he use continuity? @MohsenShahriari

Comment: @Aqua Continuity is given in the original post, and this answer is trying to prove $f(x)=Ax^2+B$ gives the class of all solutions, which is not true if you don't have the assumption of continuity. without continuity, the class of all solutions would consist of those of the form $f(x)=A(x^2)+b$ for additive $A$ and constant $b$. The last bit of the answer only shows that $F$ is additive; to get linearity, one uses continuity.